# Como puedo obtener la suma total de una columna en una tablade mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla de productos y queria hacer la suma de la fila precio
en php. ¿Como debería escribir  el código select?

Intente hacer lo de esa manera:

```
$consulta="Select SUM(precio) FROM productos";
```

No funciona. Ayuda.

Answer (score 5):

Yo lo que suelo hacer cuando tengo una función que saca un resultado de una operación (ya sea suma, media, etc) en una columna, es darle un alias, de forma que el nombre de la columna que te da como resultado de la consulta se llame de esta forma:

```
$consulta="SELECT SUM(precio) as TotalPrecios FROM productos";
$resultado=$con -> query($consulta);
$fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

$TotalPrecios=$fila['TotalPrecios']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta
```

Con el "as" lo que haces no es crear una nueva fila, simplemente le das un nombre a la columna que devuelve tu consulta. Si tuvieras una consulta cualquiera y quisieras que tu campo "precio" se llamara "precioUnitario" para diferenciarlo que otro campo de la consulta lo harías con esa sentencia: ... precio as precioUnitario...

Esto te hace más fácil acceder al resultado de la consulta desde el array asociativo que creas en la variable $fila.

Comment: Gracias @IreneA  por su ayuda .. Si entiendo bien según tu código   debo tener una fila que guarda  el resulta de la suma ?

Comment: Gracias @Irene me ayudo mucho tu codigo :) Salute

Comment: De nada!! Me alegro!! No te olvides de marcar esta pregunta como solucionada ;-) suerte con tu desarrollo ;-)

Answer (score 0):

La función "sum()" retorna la suma de los valores que contiene el campo especificado. Por ejemplo, queremos saber la cantidad de libros que tenemos disponibles para la venta:

```
select sum(cantidad) from libros;
```

Comment: Gracias @Carlos lo habia hecho asi , me devuelvo 0... y me dice que mysqli_fetch esta esperando al menos 2 parametros...

Answer (score 0):

```
prueba de la siguiente manera quizas funcione.

<?php


        require('conexion.php');

        $consultas="SELECT *  FROM alumnos";

        $resultados=$conectahugo->query($consultas);

        while($columnas=$resultados->fetch_assoc()){

        echo $columnas['id'],' ';
        echo $columnas['nombre'],' ';
        echo $columnas['apellidos'],' ';
        echo $columnas['edad'],' ';


        echo '<br>';
        }
```

?>