# ¿Cómo sumar todos los valores de una columna de mi tabla de base de datos wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

La idea es almacenar algunos valores en variables php para luego utilizarlas en una operación de regla de tres simple y condiciones. Estoy construyendo un apartado de calificación total de todas las opiniones de mi web el cual será visual con las famosas estrellas. Las variables son las siguientes:

Tope máximo de estrellas serían 5.

```
$numFilas = Número de opiniones que hay en tabla de mi base de datos;
$total =  $numFilas * 5;
$sumTotal = La suma de todos los valores de una columna específica llamada "estrellasquizz"
```

Por ahora tengo esto con respecto a mi pregunta:

```
<?php global $wpdb;
    $testimonios_table = $wpdb->prefix."opiniones";
    $sumtotal = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT estrellasquizz, SUM(estrellasquizz) FROM $testimonios_table WHERE id = 2" );
    foreach ($sumtotal as $st) {
        echo $st->estrellasquizz;
    } ?>
```

Con el foreach me imprime el resultado de la suma, pero sin el foreach solo me imprime la palabra Array. Espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de comprender tu pregunta. no estas imprimiendo la suma de nada, estas imprimiendo el valor del campo estrellasquizz que no es la suma de nada.. el campo que suma, tiene otro nombre. proba ese query directo en la db y vas a ver. sumtotal es un array, el array del resultado que trajiste. como no agrupaste en tu query (con group by) trae mas filas de las que pensas.

Comment: Podría servir esto pero no lo sé:https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99999/como-puedo-obtener-la-suma-total-de-una-columna-en-una-tablade-mysql